# Twig path without default locale

Tags: php, symfony, routes, localization, twig

in my Symfony 3.3 project I use locale system to change the user language. I have configured my routing to allow the 'en' version for not having it in the url.

```
acme_front_office:
    resource: "@AcmeFrontOfficeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /{_locale}
    defaults: { _locale: 'en'}
    requirements:
        _locale: '|en|fr'
```

So those url redirect all to the same page :

```
/home
/en/home
/fr/home
```

But in my twig templates the {{ path() }} function set by default the right locale except that when my user see the english version of the website I want that the generated url head to `/home` and not `/en/home`.

If you have a clue on how to do that without changing all the `path()` calls to override the _locale param I will be very thankful.

Have a good day ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some digging, the solution that I came up with is to rewrite some parts of the Symfony Routing system. If you want to check the solution you can find the code in the following gitlab repo, in the `Routing` dir.

[TranslateBundle Repo](https://github.com/weglot/translate-bundle)